# How Can I Use ImportHTML to Fetch My Modem's Stats Webpage?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

### Problem

I'm trying to use the Google Sheet [ImportHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) function to pull in stats from my modem's signal page at `http://192.168.100.1/cmSignal.htm`.  It looks something like this:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://192.168.100.1/cmSignal.htm","table",4)
```

Simple enough, but the function simply returns

> ERROR: could not return url `"http://192.168.100.1/cmSignal.htm"`, something that I've seen to varying degrees on a couple other posts in SE.

### Suspicion

Although I haven't been able to spot documentation which says so explicitly, it looks like functions in Google Sheets are performed "remotely," as in where the sheet is stored or processed on Google's end.  This effectively means I can't use the function to pull data from a local website like the modem's address because an external machine to my LAN has no idea where "192.168.100.1" is.

I suppose it's possible to set up some kind of forwarding, but I'm fairly unsure if ImportHTML supports custom ports.

### Question and Requirements

**Question:**  Is it possible to use functions like ImportHTML on a website only accessible on my LAN *without resorting to some external scripting method*?

I'd like to do this solely in Google Sheets without the need for pre-processing the webpage first in something else.  Thanks for any help with this!

**Note:** I understand that there are probably a million other ways to get the data I want, but I am particularly interested in this route.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Powershell.

I'm using:

```
$url = 'http://192.168.100.1/cmSignalData.htm'
$r = Invoke-WebRequest $url
.\Get-WebRequestTable.ps1 $r -TableNumber 3
```

which returns:

```
Signal Stats (Codewords)                                           Bonding Channel Value                                             
------------------------                                           ---------------------                                             
Channel ID                                                         54                                                                
Total Unerrored Codewords                                          5117105038                                                        
Total Correctable Codewords                                        26                                                                
Total Uncorrectable Codewords                                      1643
```

And try using different table numbers to scrape that data that you want.

Just grab the invoke-Webrequest script from [here](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2015/01/05/extracting-tables-from-powershells-invoke-webrequest/).